# Magento 1.9 : I have a very strange Magento problem

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sql, querystring, prefix

**Error :**

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'i1115580_mg3.sales_flat_shipment_track' doesn't exist

**Query:**

```
SELECT track_number FROM sales_flat_shipment_track
```

Comment: Did you check this table `sales_flat_shipment_track` in your database ?

Comment: please confirm correct database configured in project also confirm `sales_flat_shipment_track` table is exist in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using **table prefix** which is causing this, open up `app/etc/local.xml`

you'll find following code

```
        <db>
            <table_prefix><![CDATA[i1115580_mg3]]></table_prefix>
        </db>
```

where `i1115580_mg3` is your table prefix.